# ionic2 Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: cordova is not defined..when using InAppBrowser plugin

Tags: ionic2

Following other answer, try a lot of time ald.. no error showing, but cannot click the button. When click the error showing like title.

Tried:

1.download plugin `npm install -g typings` (nothing happen)

2.add `declare var cordova:any;` , after add this no error show, cordova can use, but after click the button new error showing...(error in title)

**service.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <button (click)="launch()" style="width:30%" ion-button color="danger" round>测试</button>
</ion-content>
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { ServiceDataProvider } from '../../providers/service-data';
declare var cordova:any;
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-service',
  templateUrl: 'service.html',
})
export class ServicePage {
  users:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public serviceData:ServiceDataProvider,
    public platform:Platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
  }
  launch(url:any){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", "location=yes");
    });
  };

}
```

Comment: are you running this in a device or browser?

Comment: run it  in browser

Comment: Cordova is not loaded in browser when you do `ionic serve` by design.. You need to run in an emulator or a device

Comment: After I click the button error showing
'ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
ReferenceError: cordova is not defined'

Comment: Try in emulator

Comment: So u mean, I have to build ios or android first and try in my device?

Comment: OKK.. I build and try first

Comment: When I run in device, can run ald.. but when I put the real url inside cannot run in device also

Comment: You can get the Ionic DevApp from Ionic for free.. this allows you to test the app on a phone from an ionic serve command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my error.. and in app browser plugin can run in my project.

**html file**

```
<button (click)="launch()" style="width:90%" ion-button color="danger" >button</button>
```

**ts file**

```
launch(){
    this.InAppBrowser.create('This is your URL',"_blank","location=no");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have Cordova in app browser plugin installed, run the below code in terminal in your project root. More often than not, this would be the issue.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

**Update**:

When running in a browser just make sure you are not using the in app browser.

```
 if(this.platform.is("cordova"))
 {
     // Run the in app browser code
 }
 else
 {
    window.open(encodeURI(url));
 }
```